# Running the del command on a Dict randomly results in "del TypeError: 'tuple' object doesn't support item deletion"

Tags: python

This error occurs randomly, but not the first time around. It's a Dictionary, so I don't know when or why it converts into a Tuple.

Even when I debug as I'm checking for it to give the TypeError, I check the datatype and it says 'Dict'.

Here's the line that's giving me problems:

```
del db_backup[name][n]
```

- `db_backup` is a dictionary in the global scope
- `name` is a string
- `n` is an int

Here's the other times that db_backup is referenced in the program:

---

```
# Global initiliaztion
db_backup = {}
```

---

```
def init():
    global db_backup
...
    db_backup = load_database()
...
```

---

```
def load_database():
    try:
        with open('persons_db.json', 'r') as fp:
            return json.load(fp)
```

---

```
sync_db(i, rs):
...
    person_id_list = db_backup[name]
...
    person_data[i].set_p_id(int(db_backup[name][n+1]))
... 
    del db_backup[name][n]  <-- Trouble line
```

---

```
def backup_db(name, rs):
    key = create_db_key(name, rs)
    db_backup.update(key)
    with open('person_db.json', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(db_backup, fp, indent=2)
```

---

```
def create_db_key(name, rs):
    key = {}
    key.update({name: (rs[0].id_str, rs[1].id_str, rs[2].id_str, r[3].id_str)})
    return key
```

---

Comment: You're trying to delete an element of a tuple. You can't do that, so stop trying.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It works flawlessly other times.

Comment: The fact that it sometimes works is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see in the documentation [`tuple`s are immutable](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

> ```
> >>> t = 12345, 54321, 'hello!'
>
> ...
>
> >>> # Tuples are immutable:
> ... t[0] = 88888
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
> >>> # but they can contain mutable objects:
> ... v = ([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1])
> >>> v
> ([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1])
> ```

But it can contain mutable object as `list`s, therefore if you need to remove an element you can use a `list` inside your `tuple`, or use a `list` directly

e.g:

```
rs_list = [rs[0].id_str, rs[1].id_str, rs[2].id_str, r[3].id_str]
key.update({name: (rs_list)})

# or 


key.update({name: rs_list})
```

If it is impossible for backward compatibility reasons to use a `list`, and you **do** need a `tuple` you can recreate it on the fly using a generator:

e.g:

```
to_remove = [name][n] # Assuming this is a unique str.

db_backup[name] = tuple(x for x in db_backup[name] if not to_remove)
```

*Note*: the fact the it sometimes works is more of a bug rather than a feature. If it works it shouldn't.